# Relation between Schwartz space and Sobolev space $H_{1}$

Tags: fourier-analysis, sobolev-spaces, harmonic-analysis

The Schwartz space, $S(\mathbb R): = \{f\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb R): \sup_{x\in \mathbb R} |x^{\alpha} D^{\beta}f(x)|< \infty , \forall \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb N \cup \{0\} \}$ and 
$S'(\mathbb R) = \text {The Space of continuous linear functionals on} \  S(\mathbb R)$ (tempered distributions).

The Sobolev Space,

$$H_{1}:= \left \{f\in S'(\mathbb R): [\int_{\mathbb R} |\hat {f}(\xi)|^{2} (1+|\xi|^{2}) d\xi]^{\frac {1}{2}} < \infty \right \}$$

It is well know that, $S(\mathbb R)$ is  a subspace of $H_{1}$.

My question is:
Let $f\in S(\mathbb R)$ such that $|f|\not \in S(\mathbb R)$.

Is it true that $|f| \in H_{1}$ or we can produce counter example ?

Comment: It is true, actually one can prove that $f\in H^1$ implies $|f|\in H^1$. This is a result of Stampacchia.

Comment: Thanks; Can you give a explicit reference paper or some standard book name or ...; -\)

Comment: One easy way to see this is observing that $\lvert \nabla \lvert f \rvert \rvert \le \lvert \nabla f\rvert$ (gradients are taken in distributional sense: see e.g. Lieb & Loss, *Analysis* 2nd ed, Theorem 6.17). This of course uses the distributional characterization of Sobolev spaces, while you are using the Fourier one. It should be possible to prove the statement using the Fourier transform directly, but it does not look immediate to me.

Answer (score 1):

As @GiuseppeNegro pointed out, this is a result of Stampacchia. I will give you some references:

I - The original [paper](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Farchive.numdam.org%2Farticle%2FSJL_1963-1964___3_1_0.pdf&ei=GO6JUv31PNS_kQe2kYGABQ&usg=AFQjCNFqG4wrRkvqT9XZHu0yWbTUR4QPRA) of Stampacchia.

II - [Brezis](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=2&sqi=2&ved=0CDYQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fbbs.sciencenet.cn%2Fupload%2Fblog%2Ffile%2F2010%2F12%2F2010127131928961750.pdf&ei=9O-JUqbUOMnwkQeo7oCgDA&usg=AFQjCNGEZbxtZ-a_IyE9kq11fdflkeqvEg) book.

III - [Ziemer's](http://ishare.iask.sina.com.cn/download/explain.php?fileid=16734046) book.

The theorem in II is less general, but it fits well in what you need and its proof is more simple.  I will not post the pages, so you can have the pleasure of searching for it in those interesting reads.